# Homestead / Vagrant how do i use my default node set through nvm?

Tags: vagrant, homestead, vagrantfile, nvm, vagrant-provision

I have installed nvm on Homestead.

Set up an nvm alias to use the latest node version.

My Homestead Vagrant box is using this latest version.

But when i run node -v through a php script it is using another version.

Is this an alias issue and can it be overridden in the provision?

How do I get the php script to recognize the alias set in nvm?

Comment: Why the minus -1?

Answer (score 0):

I edited my Vagrant file but the bash script was still using the wrong version.

I found i needed to add

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh;  . ~/.profile; . ~/.bashrc;
```

To any bash script requiring node.